# Capturing rows till first response for a campaign in python

Tags: python

I have email campaign data capturing the time, target and response (whether the user opens the link). A response of 1 means that user has opened the content.

Sample Data:

```
senddate    userid  content  response
2016-06-01  100     50505   NaN
2016-06-01  100     50505   NaN
2016-06-01  100     50505   1
2016-06-01  100     50505   1
2016-06-02  100     50505   NaN
2016-06-02  100     50505   1
2016-06-02  100     50505   1
```

Now I want to keep only the rows till first response. I want to discard any row occurring after the first response, and I want to do this for multiple send dates.

Output Dataset:

```
    senddate    userid  content  response
    2016-06-01  100     50505   NaN
    2016-06-01  100     50505   NaN
    2016-06-01  100     50505   1
    2016-06-02  100     50505   NaN
    2016-06-02  100     50505   1
```

If anyone could help in framing the logic, it would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) to achieve this:

If you `groupby` on the 'senddate' column we can generate a boolean mask comparing the index against the `first_valid_index`, this will create a multi-index where the first level are the dates and the second level are the valud index values, we then retrieve these using `get_level_values` for that level and index using `loc`:

```
In [17]:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(your_file_path)
df.loc[df.groupby('senddate')['response'].apply(lambda x: x[x.index <= x.first_valid_index()]).index.get_level_values(1)]

Out[17]:
    senddate  userid  content  response
0 2016-06-01     100    50505       NaN
1 2016-06-01     100    50505       NaN
2 2016-06-01     100    50505       1.0
4 2016-06-02     100    50505       NaN
5 2016-06-02     100    50505       1.0
```

breakdown of the above:

```
In [18]:
df.groupby('senddate')['response'].apply(lambda x: x[x.index <= x.first_valid_index()])

Out[18]:
senddate     
2016-06-01  0    NaN
            1    NaN
            2    1.0
2016-06-02  4    NaN
            5    1.0
Name: response, dtype: float64

In [19]:
df.groupby('senddate')['response'].apply(lambda x: x[x.index <= x.first_valid_index()]).index.get_level_values(1)

Out[19]:
Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 4, 5], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: @Edchum..Thank you very much response...I realised that I have a small modification...if for same user I only want to capture rows till first response and discard all the other rows irrespective of send date....can you help me in the same?

Comment: I am editing here only...because the theme of the question would be same only..just one change in logic....

Comment: then do `df.groupby('userid')['response'].apply(lambda x: x[x.index <= x.first_valid_index()])`

Comment: Thanks!!..I have edited the question so that other's can understand.

Comment: Apology for that..I have reverted to original question...I would post a separate question for the modification....